# Swift - Can I set the value of self when calling a closure?

Tags: swift

**TLDR**: Is there a equivalent for JavaScript `call` or `apply` in Swift?

Let's say I have `Foo` class that have an instance variable `bar` and a method `baz` that receives a closure as argument:

```
class Foo {
  var bar: String = ""
  func baz(closure: (Void) -> Void) {
    closure()
  }
}
```

I want to change the `self` value inside the closure. So the code is executed by the `Foo` instance.

Like this:

```
let foo = Foo()
foo.baz {
  // I want to be able to change bar value without calling foo.bar, like this:
  bar = "Hello world"
}
// Then foo.bar would be "Hello world"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Just being curious: what is wrong with: let foo = Foo(); foo.baz { foo.bar = "Hello world" } ?

Comment: In my case `foo` would be `someVariableWithAReallyLongName` and I was going to perform a lot of sets of it's properties, I just wanted it to be cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access Foo's members in the closure in the way you've described, but what you can do is modify the closure to take an instance of Foo as an argument, and pass in `self`. The result could look something like this.

```
class Foo {
    var bar: String = ""
    func baz(closure: (this: Foo) -> Void) {
        closure(this: self)
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.baz { this in
    this.bar = "Hello world"
}

print(foo.bar) // Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic type version, which looks closer to `call` in javascript.

```
class Foo {
    var bar: String = ""
}

func call<T>( this: T, closure: (T->Void) ){
    closure(this)
}

let foo = Foo()

call(foo){ this in
    this.bar = "Hello World"
}
```